# How do you properly apply hover css to <li> elements with list-style-type: none?

Tags: css

I have a list with two anchor tags for each list item, one floated left and the other right. When the list-style-type of the containing  element is disc, hovering between the two  elements works as I expect. But if the list-style-type is changed to none, the li:hover css doesn't seem to apply when you hover between the  elements.

I've confirmed the issue in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer.

```css
ul{
    list-style-type: disc;
    /* Replace the previous line with the one below.
        The hover styling no longer applies when the cursor is between anchor tags. */
    /* list-style-type: none; */
}

li{
    clear:both;
}

.left{
    float: left;
}

.right{
    float: right;
    opacity: 0;
}

li:hover > a{
    text-decoration: underline;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="left">Option 1</a>
        <a class="right">Only</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="left">Option 2</a>
        <a class="right">Only</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thomaslangston/xh7r9b68/

Comment: seems to be working on my end :/

Comment: I am using firefox, works for me. Same functionality with or without style as disc. What browser are you using?

Comment: I was using Chrome, but I just tested in Firefox and confirmed it works differently there as well.

Comment: I can confirm the issue in Firefox, so the problem is verifiable as posted.

Comment: The unerline works on chrome for me. I still see the text decoration behind the text. Maybe add the hover effect to the a tag directly?

Comment: I think the issue is best described in the actual fiddle, and it's there on chrome too: _The hover styling no longer applies when the cursor is **between** anchor tags._

Comment: The snippet works differently for me than the jsfiddle. In the snippet, the left word also gets underlined on hover. In the fiddle, only the "Only" is underlined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is interesting.  In your snippet, you float the the two child elements, so they are taken out of the regular content flow.

In the first example, with a disc showing, the `li` has content, so there is some height over which you can over.

If you take out set `list-style-type: none`, the bullet/disc is gone and `li` now has zero height, so hover won't do anything.

This is clearer if you add a border to the `li`.  You can fix the problem by adding `overflow: auto` to the `li` to contain the floats so that the `li` retain a non-zero height.

See the two examples below, the first showing the discs and the second without.

Note that if you add the borders, the hover is activated if you move over the border itself (needs some precision in mouse positioning).

```css
ul.ex1 {
list-style-type: disc;
}
ul.ex2 {
list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  clear: both;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
ul.ex2 li {
  overflow: auto;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  opacity: 0;
}
li:hover > a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ex1">
  <li>
    <a class="left">Option 1</a>
    <a class="right">Only</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="left">Option 2</a>
    <a class="right">Only</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ex2">
  <li>
    <a class="left">Option 1</a>
    <a class="right">Only</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="left">Option 2</a>
    <a class="right">Only</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```